# filter data in tableview

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I want to be part of a show the object,part of the country `countryID`, which is consistent with the object.
in different cities , there are object 
 i want to show that the city with Idi is equal to`‍‍countryID` .

```
for key in self.cityId{
            if key == self.countryID{
                self.countCity++
            }
        }
```

> But when I run return console

[image]

and simulator

[image]

> code :

write numberOfRowsInSection

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        for key in self.cityId{
            if key == self.countryID{
                self.countCity++
            }
        }

        return countCity
    }
```

and cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let city = cityArray[indexPath.row]
        if city.cityId == countryID{
        if let NameCity:String = city.nameCity {


            cell.textLabel?.text = NameCity
            print(NameCity)
            }
        }

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
```

parse API

```
func GetPassCity(){

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlCity){[unowned self] ( data ,response ,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print("A")
                print(error!)
            }else{


                do{
                //readin data from Server
                    let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                    //save data
                    for post in posts{
                        var postCity:City?
                        if let idCity = post["userId"] as? Int , let nameCity = post["title"] as? String{
                            postCity = City(idCity: idCity, nameCity: nameCity)

                            self.cityId.append(idCity)

                        }

                        self.cityArray.append(postCity!)

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                            print(self.countCity)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }


                    }
                }catch let error as NSError{

                    print("B")
                    print(error)
                }
            }


        }.resume()

        print(cityArray)
    }
```

Do you think that is the problem ?

Comment: you want `self.countCity += 1` or `self.countCity++`

Comment: I have done this before . But it was the error  `Expected expression after operator`

Comment: Then try unwrapping countCity as so `self.countCity!++` just make sure it is initialized and not nil

Comment: It was because of this vision

Comment: update code and problem

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is

Comment: @boidkan in different cities , there are object 
 i want to show that the city with id is equal to`  ‍‍countryID `

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You are doing comparisons such as `city.cityId == countryID` is it not working? The question is not clear.

Comment: I have two TableView .Tableview shows the first countries 
 and TableView cities of the country's second shows

Comment: my project. can you see this ?
https://mega.nz/#!RhYXmCLa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `self.countCity += 1`, `self.countCity!++`, or `++self.countCity!`. Doing `self.countCity = +1` is just setting countCity to 1. Open up a playground and try it out.

So:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    for key in self.cityId{
        if key == self.countryID{
            self.countCity!++
        }
    }

    return countCity
}
```

Comment: thanks .it's correct. but the problem is not resolved . update code

Answer (score 0):

i found solution whit use filter()

code :
write numberOfRowsInSection

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    return citySelected.count
}
```

and cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let city = citySelected[indexPath.row]

    if let NameCity:String = city.nameCity {


        cell.textLabel?.text = NameCity
        print(NameCity)

    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

parse API

func GetPassCity(){

```
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(urlCity){[unowned self] ( data ,response ,error) in
        if error != nil{
            print("A")
            print(error!)
        }else{


            do{
            //readin data from Server
                let posts = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                //save data
                for post in posts{
                    var postCity:City?
                    if let idCity = post["userId"] as? Int , let nameCity = post["title"] as? String{
                        postCity = City(idCity: idCity, nameCity: nameCity)

                        self.cityId.append(idCity)

                    }

                    self.cityArray.append(postCity!)



let filter = self.cityArray.filter({ $0.cityId == self.countryID})
                    self.citySelected = filter


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

                        print(self.countCity)
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }


                }
            }catch let error as NSError{

                print("B")
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

and return true data :)